# Update data with multiple select boxes with other option

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a form with multiple select boxes where multiple option may be selected with other option at last in the option list. Now, if I select other option then I need to view a new textbox where I can type manually.

But now problem is that that If I select other option for all (say 3) then I need to create 3 more tables in database to store them. So Is there any solution to store all these other values in a single table without any complexity?

***Note:*** I am using component cloning on it.

Comment: why u don't used other column instead of other table

Comment: Because i have multiple select option in each select boxes. I am using foreegn key relationship for that

Comment: Use AJAX to change content dinamicaly.

Comment: I am changing content dynamically, but need to store into table with multiple select values in single select box. And I also have same multiple select box.